# MESSAGE Resource '/AIDLMessageService/res' does not exist

Tags: android

I'm using the aidl tutorial from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-aidl-ipc-rpc-example/) which demonstrates aidl usage between two different applications.  If i run the project AIDLDisplayRemoteMessage I allways get the exception

> !MESSAGE Resource '/AIDLMessageService/res' does not
>   exist.

Am i missing something ?